# Annotation Exception: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I am new to Hibernate and JPA and am trying to wire up a database of movies, raters, and ratings. I keep getting the error `Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.stephenalexander.projects.movierecommender.rating.Rating.movie in com.stephenalexander.projects.movierecommender.movie.Movie.ratings`. Each Movie object and each Rater object has a OneToMany relationship with Rating. Here is how I've written things:

---

Rating:

```
package com.stephenalexander.projects.movierecommender.rating;

import com.stephenalexander.projects.movierecommender.movie.Movie;
import com.stephenalexander.projects.movierecommender.rater.Rater;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Objects;


@Entity
@Table(name="rating")
public class Rating {
    @Column(name = "rating_id")
    private Long ratingId;
    @Column(name = "rating")
    private Double ratingValue;
    private LocalDateTime time;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "rater_id", nullable = false)
    private Rater rater;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id", nullable = false)
    private Movie movie;
```

---

Movie:

```
package com.stephenalexander.projects.movierecommender.movie;

import com.stephenalexander.projects.movierecommender.rating.Rating;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "movie")
public class Movie {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.AUTO
    )

    @Column(name = "movie_id")
    private Integer movieId;
    private String title;
    private int year;
    @Column(name = "posterurl")
    private String posterUrl;
    @Column(name = "runningtime")
    private int runningTime;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "movie")
    List<Rating> ratings;
```

---

Rater:

```
package com.stephenalexander.projects.movierecommender.rater;

import com.stephenalexander.projects.movierecommender.rating.Rating;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "rater")
public class Rater {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.AUTO
    )
    @Column(name = "rater_id")
    private Long raterId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "rater")
    private List<Rating> ratings;
```

I have looked at a number of other posts, and this error seems to most commonly be caused by the mappedBy annotation referencing something other than the name of the instance variable within the owner class. I believe I've done that correctly since the Rating class has a variable named rater and a variable named movie. I'm not sure what else could be causing the error. Thanks very much for reading!

EDIT: Adding my comment from an answer here to clarify how I've thought these annotations work:

As I understand it, `List<Rating> ratings` is `mappedBy`: "movie", so the `movie` object in `Rating` by its annotation will tell you what column the relationship is built on, which is the primary key of movie and foreign key of rating, `movie_id`. Same thing with `rater_id`. Is this not how the whole thing works?

EDIT 2: Another thought I have that might be a misunderstanding... are these notations not necessary if I've set up the relationships in my psql database already? Is this redundant? I thought the point of these was to essentially allow me to navigate the queries in java more easily. I was led to these notations defining relationships after I kept trying to write queries and ran into errors leading me to believe my code had no idea these tables were related. Here is how they're all set up in PostgreSQL:

```
-----------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------------
 rating_id | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('rating_rating_id_seq'::regclass)
 rater_id  | integer                     |           | not null |
 movie_id  | integer                     |           | not null |
 rating    | smallint                    |           |          |
 time      | timestamp without time zone |           |          |
Indexes:
    "rating_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (rating_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "rating_movie_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES movie(movie_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
    "rating_rater_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (rater_id) REFERENCES rater(rater_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

```
                Table "public.rater"
  Column  |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default
----------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 rater_id | integer |           | not null |
Indexes:
    "rater_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (rater_id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "rating" CONSTRAINT "rating_rater_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (rater_id) REFERENCES rater(rater_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

```
                         Table "public.movie"
   Column    |          Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default
-------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 movie_id    | integer                |           | not null |
 title       | character varying(100) |           | not null |
 year        | smallint               |           | not null |
 runningtime | smallint               |           | not null |
 posterurl   | character varying(350) |           |          |
Indexes:
    "movie_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (movie_id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "movies_genres" CONSTRAINT "fk_movie" FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES movie(movie_id)
    TABLE "movies_directors" CONSTRAINT "fk_movie" FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES movie(movie_id)
    TABLE "movies_countries" CONSTRAINT "fk_movie" FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES movie(movie_id)
    TABLE "rating" CONSTRAINT "rating_movie_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES movie(movie_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Comment: I suspect, your `Rating` class is not picked up by auto-configuration!! Please refer to:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html !

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My Application class is annotated with ```@EnableAutoConfiguration```
```@EnableJpaRepositories```
```@SpringBootApplication```
I think that's all I have to do to set it up? EnableAutoConfiguration + ```@Entity```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was missing was the `targetEntity = Rating.class` param to `@OneToMany`. So the functional annotations within the different classes are as follows:

**Movie**

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Rating.class, mappedBy = "movie")
private List<Rating> ratings
```

**Rater**

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Rating.class, mappedBy = "rater")
private List<Rating> ratings
```

**Rating**

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "rater_id", nullable = false)
private Rater rater;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "movie_id", nullable = false)
private Movie movie;
```

Thanks to all who took a look at this!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Column(name = "movie_id")
private Integer movieId;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "movie_id", nullable = false)
private Movie movie;
```

U have a column with the same as **movie_id** in Rating and also in Movie. Hence there is a conflict.

Change either one of them.

Comment: I've tried a bunch of combinations and am not having any luck... I thought we actually wanted these to line up. Is that not supposed to reference the column that the relationship is based on? As I understand it, ```List<Rating> ratings``` is ```mappedBy```: "movie", so the ```movie``` object in ```Rating``` by its annotation will tell you what column the relationship is built on, which is the primary key of movie and foreign key of rating, ```movie_id```. Same thing with ```rater_id```. Is this not how the whole thing works? Will add this to the original post for clarity on my thinking.

Comment: Looking at some more examples, I realized what you may be referring to is the redundant raterId member variable in rating. I thought it had to have both, but it would make sense that the Rating class could have the Rater object stored by this mapping over keeping its id. I altered my Rating class and changed it above and am still getting the same errors.